# about the multirow in longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow

I use package longtable to make a table with some multirow. The lines about the multirow is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithout{table}{section}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{| p{0.05 \textwidth} | p{0.6 \textwidth} | p{0.1 \textwidth} | p{0.1 \textwidth} |}
\caption{\bf PS(V) 1.8c-12 vs PV 3.301-539} \label{appendix3} \\
\hline
   \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bf Steps}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf PS(V) 1.8c-12} 
         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf PV 3.301-539}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf PV 3.301-539} \\ 
      &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf According to}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf According to} \\
      &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf Gyaltsab}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf Kedrup}       \\
\hline\hline
\endfirsthead

   \multicolumn{4}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{}: Outline of PS(V) 1.8c-12}} \\
\hline
   \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bf Steps}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf PS(V) 1.8c-12}
         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf PV 3.301-539}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf PV 3.301-539} \\
      &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf According to}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf According to} \\
      &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf Gyaltsab}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf Kedrup}       \\
\hline    
\endhead

\hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{{\tiny Continued on next page}} \\
\hline
\endfoot 

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
   1111 & 222 & \multirow{2}{*}{multi row} & 4444 \\
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-4}
    111 & 222 &                            & 4444 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

However, It turns out that a "2*" as the content in the cell, as follows.

[image]

Please tell me what's wrong with that.

Comment: Please, make a complete example of code that we can play with.

Comment: @egreg the example is available.

Comment: Please, paste the code, select it and click on the `{}` button, rather than the `“` one for block quotes.

Comment: The problem is simply that the line `\usepackage{multirow}` is missing in the preamble. And the problem is also that you don't check the log file for errors; there **must** be an error saying that `\multirow` is undefined.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is simply solved by adding `\usepackage{multirow}`

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem of question is already solved with *gernot* comment above, so this answer focused on off-topic issues of question:

- with `makecell` macro `thead` is simpler to define headers of columns
- with proper calculation of column width the table width is accurate equal to text width

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, 
            makecell,   % <-- missed in question MWE, pointed in Gernot comment
            multirow}   % <-- added for columns headers
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{section}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{longtable}{| p{\dimexpr0.12\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax} 
                      | p{\dimexpr0.40\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax} 
                      | p{\dimexpr0.24\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}  
                      | p{\dimexpr0.24\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax} |}
\caption{\bf PS(V) 1.8c-12 vs PV 3.301-539} 
    \label{appendix3}                                           \\
    \hline
\thead[b]{Steps}
    &   \thead[b]{PS(V) 1.8c-12}
         &  \thead[b]{PV 3.301-539\\ According to\\ Gyaltsab}    
            &   \thead[b]{PV 3.301-539\\ According to\\ Kedrup} \\
    \hline\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{\bf PS(V) 1.8c-12 vs PV 3.301-539 (cont.)}            \\ % <--changed 
    \hline
\thead[b]{Steps}
    &   \thead[b]{PS(V) 1.8c-12}
         &  \thead[b]{PV 3.301-539\\ According to\\ Gyaltsab}
            &   \thead[b]{PV 3.301-539\\ According to\\ Kedrup} \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|r|}{\tiny Continued on next page}              \\
    \hline
\endfoot
    \hline \hline
\endlastfoot
% table contents
1111    &   222     &   \multirow{2}{=}{multi row}  &   4444    \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-4}
111     &   222     &                               &   4444    \\
    \end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

In the case, that the text width is wider than considered in above MWE, you can accommodate column width accordingly.